# Json Object get or getString Giving compile error in Jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, exception

So,After my hean banging for 3 hours finally asking for help

```
<%@ page import="net.sf.json.*" %>

..
.
.



<%
     while (rs.next()) {
     %>
      <%
    json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(rs.getString(3));
    System.out.println(json.toString());

    System.out.println(json.getString('site_caption'));//Compiler failed
    System.out.println(json.get('site_caption'));//Compier failed

    }
    %>
```

the above code printing  in console

```
{ "font_color" : "#0079cd",
  "site_background" : { "color" : "",
      "image" : "",
      "selected" : "image"
    },
  "site_caption" : "<p>Site Caption</p>\r\n",
  "site_description" : "<p>Site Description</p>\r\n",
  "site_logo" : { "image" : "1361858536dyn007or53.gif",
      "selected" : "image",
      "text" : ""
    }
}
```

but when i am trying to print

```
    System.out.println(json.getString('site_caption'));//Compiler failed
    System.out.println(json.get('site_caption'));//Compier failed
```

Not even giving the proper error message

I am getting harassed by the same error message

```
Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:933)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
```

Please drag me out of this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the compiler error output? Without those details its a hard guess indeed...

Comment: What is your servlet container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your keys should be escaped with double quotes `"`, not single quote `'`. E.g:

```
System.out.println(json.getString("site_caption"));
```

Comment: Tried with  System.out.println(json.get('font_color'));   not working